# Do 'limit points' as I used to learn about for the metric topology still exist in the Zariski topology?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, metric-spaces

Considering the three lines $V_{1}, V_{2}, V_{3} \in\mathbb{A}^{2}_{R}$ and how some of the complementary (open) sets contain a point and some don't - I wanted to know if limit points are still used or how to define them even though from the geometric point of view closure of a set is different from the closure in metric topological space.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On any topological space $X$, the concept of limit point makes sense: the set of limit points of $Y\subset X$ is$$\bigl\{x\in X\mid\text{if $N$ is a neighborhood of $x$, then }(N\cap Y)\setminus\{x\}\ne\emptyset\bigr\}.$$Also, on any topological space $X$, the closure of a set $Y$ is the set$$\overline Y=\bigl\{x\in X\mid\text{if $N$ is a neighborhood of $x$, then }N\cap Y\ne\emptyset\bigr\},$$whether or not the topology of $X$ is induced by a metric.